# Using RegEx in a CodeIgniter route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm in the progress of converting an old site over to CodeIgniter which involves preserving some old URLS. I need to be able to pass a single character, either #, A-Z or a-z. Here is my pattern:

```
/^[a-zA-Z#]$/
```

It seems to work out just fine in all of my tests by passing it to preg_match(). I simply added it to a CI route like this:

```
$route['(:any)/(/^[a-zA-Z#]$/)'] = "collection/view/$1/alpha/$2";
```

and it is giving me this error:

```
Message: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/'
```

I can't for the life of me massage this pattern to allow CI to accept it. I think it's being escaped strangely. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I dove in to /core/Router.php just to see what CI was doing with the pattern. Here is what CI is using:

```
#^(.+)/(/^[a-zA-Z\#]$/)$#
```

It is converting the entire passed string into one big pattern.

SOLVED:

After figuring out that CI attempts to create one big pattern I rewrote the pattern from scratch and removed the (:any). I have also replaced the # with a +. Here is my final solution:

```
 $route['(^(.+)/([a-zA-Z\+]$))'] = "collection/view/$2/alpha/$3";
```

If anyone has a more elegant pattern, please feel free to post it. Thanks!

Comment: `#` is a special character in a URL, I don't think you can use it in a route because the server cannot read it, or anything that comes after it.

Comment: I as thinking that too so I removed the # and just tried to test with a-zA-Z and still not getting a match.

Answer (score 2):

```
$route['(:any)/(^([a-zA-Z]|\#))'] = "collection/view/$1/alpha/$2";
```

Comment: That took care of the error but I'm not getting a match with:

     http://example.com/test/a

Comment: Still no match. I need that ^ regardless as I want to ensure only a single char is being passed. I've also removed all other routes to see if there was a conflict and no go. Pretty lost at this point.

Comment: @madzilla, i think opening `/` and closing `/` will be added auto by CI. try this once.

Comment: If I remove them I get another error. See my edit in original post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to escape # in regex. Try using

`/^([a-zA-Z#])$/`

instead of

`(/^([a-zA-Z]|#)$/)`

Comment: If I don't escape, I'm getting the error above. But I can shorten the pattern to the one you suggested. I could even remove the ().

Comment: Maybe trying putting the parens to capture $2 inside the slashes? Edited answer to reflect this.